# Active tab not showing content on page load in Foundation 5

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation's JavaScript framework to create a tab-based content container that changes the panel content when the user clicks on a tab. (This is merely the standard tab behavior as described in Zurb's [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html#tabs-deeplink-3).)

I have three panels, one of which is supposed to be the default one active upon on page load. This panel is marked as the default by its corresponding `<li>` tag having the attribute "active":

```
<ul class="tabs vertical" data-tab data-options="deep-linking:true">
    <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel1">Listings & Downloads</a></li>
    <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2">Competitions</a></li>
    <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel3">Commentary</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-content">
    <div id="panel1" class="content">
        (This content is supposed to be displayed automatically on page load, but it doesn't appear until the user clicks on the tab for panel1.)
    </div>
    <div id="panel2" class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div id="panel3" class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
</div>
```

I know that the correct CSS is being applied to the "active" class because the background and hover colors are being rendered appropriately.

I tried to re-trigger the tab content with JavaScript by using "**$(document).foundation();**" and "**$(document).foundation('tab', 'reflow');**" as described in the documentation, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the "active" class to the markup for the panel content---not merely to the tab:

```
<div class="tabs-content">
    <div id="panel1" class="content active">
    [....]
</div>
```

This HTML correctly displays the content of #panel1 on page load.